# ComboBox, jump to specific item

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have to programm a windows store app, for a class at university. I created a ComboBox in order to select the year. If you select the ComboBox, a list appears with numbers from 2013 to 2100. But when the list appears the default view is somewhere around, is there anyway to make the list appear at the current year? or at least make it appear beginning with the first value.

Thanks in advance, Beejay

Answer (score 0):

This should work quite well (in XAML):

```xml
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"/> <!--after that all your attributes-->
```

If you want to do it in code:

```
MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks mate.
This does help at least a little. If I do this in XAML, it works perfectly. But if I try to do it in Code, it's like it doesn't have an effect. This is the Code I'm using:

`       public Administration()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            DateTime currentDate=DateTime.Now;
            ComboBox_year.SelectedItem = currentDate.Year;
            
        }`

Comment: @Bbejay Try currentDate.Year - 2013 instead.

Comment: Code looks like this now:  
`year_box.SelectedItem = currentDate.Year - 2013;`   
still nothing happening :/

Comment: I've tried around a little. Funny thing is, I only seem to be ably to address the ComboBox via Index. This works both ways: xaml or code. But as soon as I try to address it via value, nothing seems to happen. Is this a common bug?

Comment: That is because the SelectedItem has to equal an item from your ItemSource. year_box.SelectedItem = ItemSource.First(x => x == currentDate.Year);